# Kubernetes API : add label to pod

Tags: kubernetes

With command, I can add label as below

```
kubectl label pod POD_NAME KEY1=VALUE1
```

How could I do that from kubernetes API?

I guess it can be done by `PATCH /api/v1/namespaces/{namespace}/pods/{name}`

Here is pod.json

```
{
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "kind": "Pod",
    "metadata": {
        "labels": {
            "key1": "value1"
        }
    }
}
```

I tried with following command

```
KUBE_TOKEN=$(</var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token)
curl --request PATCH --insecure \
      --header "Authorization: Bearer $KUBE_TOKEN"  \
      --data "$(cat pod.json)" \
      https://$KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST:$KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_PORT/api/v1/namespaces/$POD_NAMESPACE/pods/$POD_NAME
```

And it returns

```
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {},
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "the server responded with the status code 415 but did not return more information",
  "details": {},
  "code": 415
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Set content-type to `application/json-patch+json` and specify the patch in http://jsonpatch.org format.

```
$ cat > patch.json <<EOF
[ 
 { 
 "op": "add", "path": "/metadata/labels/hello", "value": "world" 
 } 
]
EOF
$ curl --request PATCH --data "$(cat patch.json)" -H "Content-Type:application/json-patch+json" https://$KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST:$KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_PORT/api/v1/namespaces/$POD_NAMESPACE/pods/$POD_NAME
```

Comment: `Content-Type: application/merge-patch+json` works for me

Comment: I have done this to add simple labels like:  "hello=world", in the example above.  But, can you use this approach to add a label like:  "domain.com/hello=world"?  "path":"/metadata/labels/domain.com/hello" doesn't seem to work, nor do various methods I've tried to escape the "/" in "domain.com/hello".

Comment: Have you tried merge patch.  Search for merge in https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/devel/api-conventions.md

Comment: @DavidMcKinley, If you need to refer to a key with `~` or `/` in its name, you must replace them by `~0` and `~1` respectively. So for your example `"path":"/metadata/labels/domain.com~1hello"`

Answer (score 0):

In order to use JSON Patch properly, you have to set content type to `application/json-patch+json` as defined in [RFC6902](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902). Works for me.